# Индекс выбранной ячейки TableView в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Как можно получить номер столбца и строки при клике на ячейку в TableView?
Придумал вот такой вот дуратский способ найти номер столбца:

```
((TablePosition) tableS.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0)).getTableColumn().getText()
```

А потом сравнивать его с названиями столбцов заведомо известных.
Это очееень криво, понимаю.
А какой способ является хорошим?

Кроме того потом нужно будет узнать содержимое первой ячейки в выбранной строке.

То есть в результате нужно знать всего содержимое первой ячейки в выбранной строке и номер ячейки в этой строке по которой кликнули.

Answer (score 2):

```
getTableView().getItems().get(CustomerButtonCell.this.getIndex())
```